# Empty QT GUI crashes after linking DLLs

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dll, stm32

For my project i need a GUI and library called "STM32CubeProgrammer CLI".
They include some example C++ projects with VS and QT (both only command line, no GUI).
I'm able to compile and work with them.

In the next step I created a QT Widgets Application and add the STM library but the program crash instantly.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h
    $$PWD/../../../include/CubeProgrammer_API.h \
    $$PWD/../../../include/DeviceDataStructure.h \

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui


#comment out that line and the programm works
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../lib/ -lCubeProgrammer_API

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../include
```

This is the main.cpp I don't edit any "window" or other files, I don't even use a function of the dll.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The linker find the dlls, but the program only crashes if I'm using a GUI, a simple cmd program dont crash. Just for fun I added Qlibrary, but the program crashes befor.

I'm using qmake, QT 5.14.2 MinGW-32bit and QT Creator 4.11.1.

Comment: when you add the line in config file and save the file does it show any errors?

Comment: No, errors. I did also a full rebuild.

Comment: My guess is you have a different version of Qt dlls in your path or possibly your crt